# Deadlock in malloc_atfork

Tags: c, linux, glibc

Our multi-threaded process is deadlocked in several threads, each showing the 3 frames below at the top of the stack.  GDB shows that another thread is stuck in fork (called via popen), which is presumably why malloc_atfork, instead of malloc, is being called to allocate memory.

```
#0  0x00007f4f02c4aeec in __lll_lock_wait_private () from 
/usr/lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007f4f02bc807c in _L_lock_14817 () from /usr/lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007f4f02bc51df in malloc_atfork () from /usr/lib64/libc.so.6
```

There is a RedHat bug (https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=906468) about a deadlock in glibc between fork and malloc and other reports about deadlocks in malloc_atfork.

And this link, https://sourceware.org/ml/libc-alpha/2016-02/msg00269.html, from Feb, 2016, contains a patch for removing malloc_atfork.

Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

Comment: **Don't fork in a multi-threaded process** (except when followed by `exec`). *"After a fork() in a multithreaded program, the child can safely call only async-signal-safe functions (see signal-safety(7)) until such time as it calls execve(2)."*

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: Calling `popen` from a multi-threaded process is completely valid and reasonable. So is calling `fork` then immediately one of the exec-family functions (although in that case `posix_spawn` would be preferable).

Comment: Can you show a full backtrace, not just the first 3 frames?

Comment: In our 54 threaded process, there are 17 threads deadlocked in __lll_lock_wait_private.  One of the threads had __fopen_internal() as the 3rd frame.  Other threads have our local functions as the 3rd frame.

Answer (score 4):

While this is a bug in glibc, it should not be able to happen except when you are calling `fork` from an async-signal context, where it has interrupted code that's already holding the `malloc` lock and the interrupted code cannot make forward progress. Otherwise, it's another thread holding the lock, and that thread should eventually make forward progress and allow the `fork` to continue.

Are you possibly calling `popen` from a signal handler? If so, that's not valid usage, and you should expect it to be able to fail in many other ways, not just this one.

Comment: Well, it wasn't me.

Comment: Not my downvote. But, the bug report does not involve any async safe call violations. Have an upvote.

Comment: R, thanks for your answer.  The popen call is made from a pthread function as follows: popen("ntpq -p | awk 'NR==3 {print $9}'", "r")).  But when I run "ntpq -p" from the command line, I get a "ntpq: read: Connection refused" error.  Do you think the error from ntpq could cause this problem?

Comment: Please don't accept my answer at this time, as I don't think it's solved your problem.